# Replace characters before question mark of current URL with javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Is there a way to replace all characters before the question mark in a URL via  a javascript bookmarklet?

I found a way to replace parts in the URL but only if the current url is the same all the time.

But my url is different with alot of subpages so i need to isolate everything before the question Mark

**Example 1:**

**http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html**?query=bucky&searchOnTitleAndDescription=true&categoryId=356&postcode=

Should be changed to:

**http://www.rss2search.nl/marktplaats/zoek.php**?query=bucky&searchOnTitleAndDescription=true&categoryId=356&postcode=

Can i change it by selecting everything before the question mark?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, please have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you could improve your question. For example: always try to provide example code of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your URL into an array:

```
var arr = 'http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query=buck...'.split('?');
```

Join the new URL text and the second element of `arr` together:

```
var text = 'http://www.rss2search.nl/marktplaats/zoek.php';
var out = [text, arr[1]].join('?');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gg0g5z07/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done like this...

```
var url = "http://www.rss2search.nl/marktplaats/zoek.php";
location.href = url + location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("?"));
```

For your bookmarklet, add this as the url...

```
javascript:(function(){location.href="http://www.rss2search.nl/marktplaats/zoek.php"+location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("?"));return false;})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
// This regex pattern will take whatever string before question mark
var re = /(.+)\?/; 

var str = 'http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query=bucky&searchOnTitleAndDescription=true&categoryId=356&postcode=';

// And then replace with this string
var subst = 'http://www.rss2search.nl/marktplaats/zoek.php'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```